# freeSwitch ESL api api originate response -ERR NORMAL_CLEARING

Tags: freeswitch

i neel make a call from my application to internal use ESL
use nodejs 'modesl' module

ESL api call response NORMAL_CLEARING WHY ???

api originate {ignore_early_media=true,origination_uuid=e0911776-e4bf-11eb-862f-d3d81f5727e2,originate_timeout=60,hangup_after_bridge=true}sofia/internal/1000@domain &playback(message)

response

````
  headers: [
    { name: 'Content-Type', value: 'api/response' },
    { name: 'Content-Length', value: 21 }
  ],
  hPtr: null,
  type: undefined,
  subclass: undefined,
  body: '-ERR NORMAL_CLEARING\n'
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

According to the content of API call, the outgoing call will hangup automatically after end of playback.

Comment: change  from 1000@domain to  1000%domain and it work! thanks https://github.com/fiorix/go-eventsocket/blob/master/examples/client/client.go